# Fastest way to find text in file

Tags: c#, .net, string, file

So I'm looking for a way to efficiently search for text in a file. Right now I'm using this:

```
using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, 1024 * 1024, FileOptions.SequentialScan))
using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        int index = 0;
        while ((index = line.IndexOf(searchText, index, StringComparison.Ordinal)) != -1)
        {
            index += searchText.Length;
        }
    }
}
```

However, I was wondering if there was a way to more efficiently search the file. I was thinking of maybe searching for the text in buffers, but I'm not sure how.
Thanks.

EDIT:
Without calling IndexOf, I get around 1600ms. With index of, it's around 7400ms.

EDIT:
I have a basic implementation of chunk reading, and it got the time down to 740ms. (No reading lines)
It still has lots of work, but I basically read a chunk at a time and take index of.

Comment: It depends on what the bottleneck is, if its the file read, well you are not going to get much faster apart from adjusting buffer size.

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13959429/c-sharp-searching-large-text-file) help?

Comment: @TheGeneral I increment index because I want to find all occurrences in that string.

Comment: @VS-ux yeah i figured that eventually.

Comment: @Hayden IndexOf is already faster than Boyer-Moore algorithm. I think it's because I'm calling IndexOf too many times. I probably have to to it on a large buffer.

Comment: You could also break this into parallel workloads probably if you are reading large buffers, however you will hit an IO bottle neck eventually

Comment: I tried parallelizing it, but it seemed even slower. (Parallelizing File.ReadLines)

Comment: Do you care what line the search term is on?

Comment: No, but possibly in the future

Comment: @VS-ux parallelising the file read won't help you. you might have 2,4,8,16 or 128 cores to calculate stuff - but only _one_ storage device from which to read.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann Well I think you could use MMF, but it might still be IO bound

Comment: Memory mapped files or not, your file reads will likely be slower than the actual searching (if i were to take a guess)

Comment: @TheGeneral Without calling IndexOf, I get around 1600ms. With index of, it's around 7400ms.

Comment: The data can be whatever the user wants, and the search terms can be anything aswell. Also I tested your code and Parallelizing doesn't really help in this scenario.

Comment: I repeat TheGeneral. Even though your usage of `IndexOf` is a bit slower, you should first profile if your file-access is not even slower? Why should you optimize some milliseconds for `IndexOf`, when your actual bottleneck is far bigger. Don´t hunt for every optimization, just make those that **matter**.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Without calling IndexOf, I get around 1600ms. With index of, it's around 7400ms. However, I think I shouldn't call indexof for every line. I should instead read buffers, and then extend to next line if needed.

Comment: @TheGeneral I tested it with the standbylist (file cache) cleared. Also, my test file is about 400MB large but every line is only like 5 bytes large. That equates to many lines.

Comment: @TheGeneral I mean that instead of calling IndexOf for every line, I call it only every 1MB chunk. So if there are 10000 lines in 1MB, then I skip 9999 calls to IndexOf

Comment: @VS-ux, you are not going to get answer here, even if someone could come up with a good one its likely going to be faster or slower depending on the particular file read, and whether you want to do this by line (and other considerations). Also there are variables like your cpu speed and hdd speed which will play in to the equation. If i were you (and i am sure you are capable) just keep on bench-marking, and you will come to the best solution for you. (note, i delete most of the comments as this was getting out of hand)

Comment: Alright. Thank you TheGeneral. I will keep trying.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach from the performance point of view will be O(xl) time, where x is the length of the string being searched and l the length of the string you are trying to find.
There are few general algorithms that you can apply:

- Boyer-Moore
- Morris-Pratt
- Knuth-Morris-Pratt

I recommend you to use Boyer-Moore and here you have examples on how to implement it: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/boyer-moore-algorithm-for-pattern-searching/

Comment: I saw in many tests that IndexOf was still actually faster than Boyer-Moore

Comment: The current implementation of String.IndexOf(string) uses a naive loop to check whether a substring of some given text matches a pattern. Although this implementation is simple and easy to understand, it is very inefficient because it has to iterate through a minimum of m - n + 1 characters of the text, where m is the length of the text and n is the length of the pattern string.

Comment: However in many tests like this one: http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/algorithms/fast-text-search-with-boyer-moore IndexOf outperformed boyer

Comment: I tested boyer moore against larger chunks (in favor of boyer), however, it still lost by almost half.

Comment: Boyer-Moore is demonstrated as one of the fastest algorithm that works. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string-search_algorithm. I don't know what code implementation your present and in what contexts but from theoretical point of view Boyer-Moore stands as the best approach.

Comment: You're correct. However, for smaller chunks of data (I don't want to read entire file into memory), like even 1MB large, IndexOf is almost 2x faster (With StringComparison.Ordinal)

Comment: @VS-ux if you are running on Windows,  `IndexOf` calls https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnls/nf-winnls-findnlsstringex, I wouldn't be surprised to find that this is an implementation of the Boyer-Moore Algorithm with the Galil rule.